# AWS CLI Create from JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using the AWS CLI I generated JSON output of all of my security groups:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region us-west-1 --output json > westsecuritygroups
```

**Is there a way to re-create the security groups using this JSON?**

Answer (score 0):

Note, Windows AWS CLI is used for this answer.

In general, cli has `--generate-cli-skeleton` option to get json format to use for a request. Here is one for create-group:

```
aws iam create-group --group-name devops --generate-cli-skeleton
```

response:

`{
    "Path": "",
    "GroupName": ""
}`

Now, set elements with values and save as a file `c:\temp\iam-create-group.json`. Here is some useful info about Path parameter - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-friendly-names

`{
    "Path": "/corp1/nyc/cloud1/",
    "GroupName": "devops"
}`

Finally, to create a group at IAM > Groups level, run the following command:

```
aws iam create-group --group-name devops --cli-input-json file://c:\temp\iam-create-user.json
```

response:

`{
    "Group": {
        "Path": "/corp1/nyc/cloud1/",
        "GroupName": "devops",
        "GroupId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:group/corp1/nyc/cloud1/devops",
        "CreateDate": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}`

Comment: The question is about EC2 **security** groups, not IAM groups.